# Unable to redirect to a different page using react bootstrap table from one route to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap-table

I am new to [React](https://reactjs.org/). Currently, I am using [react bootstrap table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html) to populate data in my application. My task is that when the user clicks on the row of the table, it should take the parameters of the row and redirect to a different route.

My code for the [react bootstrap table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html) is as follows

```
   <BootstrapTable data={ this.state.userDetails } options={options}>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='email' isKey>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='familyName'>Family Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='givenName'>Given Name</TableHeaderColumn>
   </BootstrapTable>
```

My code for the options passed to the [react bootstrap table](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html) is as follows

```
const options={
  onRowClick:function(row, rowIndex, columnIndex, event){
    console.log(row);
    console.log(event);
    <Redirect to="/users/1" />;
  }
}
```

Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

My complete code is as follows

```
class ListView extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {userDetails:[]}
}

onSubmit(values){


/*API Call done over here as the state needed to manipulated*/
const headers={
  "Content-Type":"application/json",
  "Authorization":cookies.get('idToken'),
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
}

fetch(`${awsConfig.adminDevUrl}/users?email=${values.email}`,
       {
       method:"GET",
       headers:headers
      })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => {
              if(data.length>0){
                 this.setState({userDetails:data});
              }else{
                 this.setState({userDetails:[]});
              }
               this.props.reset();// Reset the form
      })
     .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({userDetails:[]});
      })
   }

renderField(field){

const className=`form-group`;
const Field=`${field.label=='Password'? 'password':'text'}`

  return (
    <div className={className}>
        <div className="input-group">
          <span className="input-group-addon"><i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
           <input className="form-control" type={Field} {...field.input}/>
        </div>

    </div>);
  }

render() {
  const { handleSubmit,history }=this.props;

const options={
  onRowClick:function(row, rowIndex, columnIndex, event){
    console.log(row);
    console.log(event);
    <Redirect to="/users/1" />;
  }
}


return (

  <div>
      <div>
          <NavigationBar />

           <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
              <p><b> Search Users on the Platform </b></p>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                    <Field name="email" component={this.renderField} label="Search" />
              </form>
           </div>
      </div>

      <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <BootstrapTable data={ this.state.userDetails } options={options}>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='email' isKey>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='familyName'>Family Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='givenName'>Given Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
</div>

   );
 }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Redirect />` is a component that performs a route change when rendered.
If you want to change route in this callback function, you should use the `history.push()` method. If your component is rendered by a `<Route />`, you should have `history` as props.

You can get more info about `history` here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Also, do not forget that JSX transpiles to `React.createElement(...)` that only returns a React element and does not performs anything else..

Comment: Hey Pierre, I tried history.push and this that not work. I have attached my complete code for reference. Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once by defining a state called `redirect`, then on row click set the state of `redirect`.

```
class ListView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userDetails: [],
            redirect: false
        }
    }

    /* your remaining code */

    render() {

        const { handleSubmit,history }=this.props;

        const options={
            onRowClick:function(row, rowIndex, columnIndex, event){
                this.setState({ redirect : true })
            }
        }

        // redirect only if the state is true
        if(this.state.redirect) {
            return(
                <Redirect to="/users/1" />
            )
        }

        return (

            <div>
                <div>
                    <NavigationBar />

                    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <p><b> Search Users on the Platform </b></p>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                                <Field name="email" component={this.renderField} label="Search" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <BootstrapTable data={ this.state.userDetails } options={options}>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='email' isKey>Email</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='familyName'>Family Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='givenName'>Given Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                    </BootstrapTable>
                </div>
            </div>

            );
        }


}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `react-router` in most cases events that are not propagated can be interrupted. I took the test here and could only execute using:

`onRowClick: (row, rowIndex, columnIndex, event) => location.href = '#/plannings';`